# Text sanitization Issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, sanitization

I added this code to my site to have text sanitization:

```
var re = /(<([^>]+)>)/gi;
        for (i=0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        arguments[i].value=arguments[i].value.replace(re, "");
        }
```

But somehow people are able to use the  tag and still be able to post pics on my website through the text area. Please let me know if i have the code wrong.

PS: Users were also getting away with  tags as well.

Comment: They can probably circumvent the JavaScript side .. you also need to sanitize on the server  side

Comment: Also careful with that `i` variable, it's leaking.

Comment: What do you mean? Honestly when I looked at the inputs the user put through mysql database, I only saw the html tags.

Comment: What do you mean leaking? @elclanrs

Comment: @Karthik Since you haven't defined `i` with `var`, it's become a sort of global variable. This may confuse you if you do the same thing with a loop in a different function.

Comment: So would initiating i as: var i = 0; work

Comment: @ExplosionPills how can i prevent them from circumventing through the server side?

Comment: @Karthik just check the inputs with php in a similar fashion before storing them in the DB

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780436/user-input-validation-client-side-or-server-side-php-js

Answer (score 0):

Never trust the input data.
User can simply use `curl` or something else and send `HTTP POST` request with any data in body that he want to your server.
Therefore have a rule to **validate all data at server side** before saving it to the database.

You can introduce client-side validation though to improve user experience but anyway you have to validate that input at server side when request is received.

---

**Update:**

I see that you tagged your question with `php` tag, so if your server-side application is written in PHP, you can use a [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to sanitize input data and avoid XSS, etc.
Also if you use some PHP framework it probably could have an own wrapper for HTML Purifier. For example Yii framework has it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe nothing wrong ,user just disable javascript before submit.

check in server side
like

```
 $_POST['name'] = preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $_POST['name']);
```

OR

```
 $_POST['name'] = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
```