# How to prevent the user from changing values in the HTML or the JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to make a user can change they are changing profile text color and background color.

I created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/LEQdwB)** from codepen.io

In this demo you can see when you checked any radio button then `.colored-text` div inside text will changing automatically.

I want to allow only that color:  `#fa743e,#323949,#0000,#d8dbdf`. But the problem is here if user change for example `#fa743e` to `#ffffff` using developer console the `#ffffff` color posting  in database. It is not good.

this is form :

```
<form method="post" action="">
<!--Text Color-->
<div class="renk">
  <input type="radio" id="red" class="sr ja" name="change-text-color" value="#fa743e">
  <label for="red" class="llr"></label>
</div>
<!--Background Color-->
<div class="renk"> 
   <input type="radio" id="lr" class="lr ja" name="change-background-color" value="#000000">
   <label for="lr" class="llr"></label>
</div>

</form>
```

I am using this ajax post method:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'change_theme.php',
     data: {change-text-color:$('input[name="change-text-color"]:checked').val(),change-background-color:$('input[name="change-background-color"]:checked').val()},
     beforeSend: function(){$("#posting").html('<img src="icons/ajaxloader.gif"/>'); },
     success: function(html) {
     $('.tduzalani, .temayi-degistir-alani').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
     $('.tduzalani, .temayi-degistir-alani').css('display', 'none');});
        swal({   title: "Theme was changing succuesfully!",   text: ":)",   timer: 5000 });
      }
});
```

and this is **change_theme.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'includes.php';
$colors = array( '#fa743e','#ffcc4d','#94d487','#4a913c','#89c9fa','#3b94d9','#abb8c2','#dd2e44','#f5abb5','#bfcfee','#be72ea','#ea729f','#000000','#0e1d40','#0e4034','#40310e','#451468','#ffffff','#006cff','#bb0707','#660202','#44404b','#422929','#323949');
if((isSet($_POST['change-text-color']) && in_array($_POST['change-text-color'], $colors)) || (isSet($_POST['change-change-background-color']) && in_array($_POST['change-background-color'], $colors)))
{
$text-color=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['change-text-color']);
$background-color=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['change-background-color']);

$data=$Suavi->change_theme($uid,$text-color,$background-color);

}
?>
```

Comment: everything can be done in the developer tools. on your server side.. put validation there and have a default value if settings in not present.

Comment: @OliSoproniB. I understood the server must enforce it. I use array code in change_theme.php if you check then you can see. But there is one problem. The problem is: If user change only `input[name="change-text-color"]:checked').val()` color then it is posted. but if user change two color : `change-text-color:$('input[name="change-text-color"]:checked').val(),change-background-color:$('input[name="change-background-color"]:checked').val()`

Comment: you already have the validation in your server-side code, but only need to set allowed colors in `$colors` array. Like : `$colors = array('#fa743e','#323949','#000000','#d8dbdf' );`

Comment: @GopakumarGopalan I do this in `change_theme.php` but it is only checking two value. for example if user change only change-text-color like `#fa743e` to `#555555` then the users color= `#555555` posting.  but i have no this `#555555` color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottom line: Never trust anything from the client. The client can change whatever they desire, and can even edit the data that's going to the server. If you wish to ensure they can't do something, then you will have to put checks on the only thing they can't change (The server). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780436/user-input-validation-client-side-or-server-side-php-js) is a good guide explaining the benefits of what I mentioned.

To answer your comment below:

`Javascript`:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'change_theme.php',
     data: {change-text-color:$('input[name="change-text-color"]:checked').val(),change-background-color:$('input[name="change-background-color"]:checked').val()},
     beforeSend: function(){$("#posting").html('<img src="icons/ajaxloader.gif"/>'); },
     success: function(html) {
        if ( html == "1" ) {
            $('.tduzalani, .temayi-degistir-alani').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
            $('.tduzalani, .temayi-degistir-alani').css('display', 'none');});
            swal({   title: "Theme was changing succuesfully!",   text: ":)",   timer: 5000 });
        } else {
            alert('There was an error saving this!')
        }
      }
});
```

`PHP`:

```
<?php
include_once 'includes.php';

$textcolors = array('#fa743e','#323949','#000000','#d8dbdf');
$bgcolors = array('#fa743e','#ffcc4d','#94d487','#4a913c','#89c9fa','#3b94d9','#abb8c2','#dd2e44','#f5abb5','#bfcfee','#be72ea','#ea729f','#000000','#0e1d40','#0e4034','#40310e','#451468','#ffffff','#006cff','#bb0707','#660202','#44404b','#422929','#323949');

//
if( isSet($_POST['change-text-color']) && in_array($_POST['change-text-color'], $textcolors) && isSet($_POST['change-change-background-color']) && in_array($_POST['change-background-color'], $bgcolors) )
{
    $text-color=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['change-text-color']);
    $background-color=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['change-background-color']);

    $data=$Suavi->change_theme($uid,$text-color,$background-color);
    echo 1;
}
else
{
    echo 0;
}

exit;

?>
```

Comment: I understood the server must enforce it. I use array code in change_theme.php if you check then you can see. But there is one problem. The problem is: If user change only `input[name="change-text-color"]:checked').val()` color then it is posted. but if user change two color : `change-text-color:$('input[name="change-text-color"]:checked').val(),change-bac‌​kground-color:$('input[name="change-background-color"]:checked').val()`

Comment: That's just an issue with your if statement. I would break them apart into two if/else statements. Check my answer edit.

Comment: it is something went wrong. If user change two color and post that color then successfully posting.

Comment: I'm entirely confused at what you're trying to accomplish here. Perhaps check out Gopakumars answer below if you're dealing with two different arrays, or rephrase your question so I can better understand it. I need to know exactly what needs to happen when a user submits the form.

Comment: I need like if theme color is invalid then I want to open this warning.: `The theme color value is invalid, try again by selecting a color`

Comment: I just updated my post again! (Last time). This should do what you're looking for.

Comment: the ajax everytime showing `alert('There was an error saving this'');` what is wrong ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71118/discussion-between-danbopes-and-innovation).

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can prevent users from changing stuff in their console. All the front-end code (HTML, JS, CSS) is sent to the browser, then anybody can view it and change it to their will. If you really want to limit the allowed colors, make a server-side check.

Answer (score 0):

In the server-side code **change_theme.php** you should have two seperate arrays for textcolors and background colors.

```
<?php
    include_once 'includes.php';
    $bgcolors = array('#fa743e','#ffcc4d','#94d487','#4a913c','#89c9fa','#3b94d9','#abb8c2','#dd2e44','#f5abb5','#bfcfee','#be72ea','#ea729f','#000000','#0e1d40','#0e4034','#40310e','#451468','#ffffff','#006cff','#bb0707','#660202','#44404b','#422929','#323949');
    $textcolors = array('#fa743e','#323949','#000000','#d8dbdf');
    if((isSet($_POST['change-text-color']) && in_array($_POST['change-text-color'], $textcolors)) || (isSet($_POST['change-change-background-color']) && in_array($_POST['change-background-color'], $bgcolors)))
    {
        $text-color=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['change-text-color']);
        $background-color=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['change-background-color']);

        $data=$Suavi->change_theme($uid,$text-color,$background-color);

    }
?>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I still try this almost same