# Vuejs avoid changing data in production mode by using DOM

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a beginner question about produciton mode in vuejs. I'm using the minified version of vue and i have a Question. How can i avoid accessing and changing the value of data by using DOM here an example: for accessing ->  `document.getElementsByClassName('VueInstance')[0].__vue__.$children[0].$data.foo` and for changing `document.getElementsByClassName('VueInstance')[0].__vue__.$children[0].$data.foo = "bar"` ? Its there any possibility to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Client-side JavaScript isn't secure by design, i.e. user has full control over the script that runs in user's browser. Considering that a user has enough access rights locally, the code always can be read and modified. Security measures that are applicable to client-side code only make this process more complicated.

Never trust anything from the client. The client can change whatever they desire, and can even edit the data that's going to the server. If you wish to ensure they can't do something, then you will have to put checks on the only thing they can't change

[How to prevent the user from changing values in the HTML or the JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561676/how-to-prevent-the-user-from-changing-values-in-the-html-or-the-javascript)

[Can react state be tampered with to bypass security measures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417001/can-react-state-be-tampered-with-to-bypass-security-measures)